# Numerical method for wave equation with nonlinear forcing in 1+1 D

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I am looking for numerical method to solve the equation
$$
\square 
\phi = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} = \lambda \phi^3 \,
$$
for **real** $\phi = \phi(x,t)$ and real $\lambda > 0$. I am interested in solutions on $x \in (0,l)$ and $t \in (0,t_{max})$ and supply the following boundary conditions: $\phi(0,t) = \phi(l,t) = 0$ and $\phi(x,0) = f(x)$ and $\dot{\phi}(x,0) = g(x)$.

I don't know much about numerical solutions of PDEs, but I have tried the most simple method I could think of and it was not converging to the correct solution.

**Method**
I was thinking as follows. Let the step in $x$ and $t$ be the same, $\Delta$. Then, for a particular $x,t$ I can look at the partial derivatives and write them as
$$
\square \phi (x,t) \approx \frac{\phi(x+\Delta,t)+\phi(x-\Delta,t)-\phi(x,t+\Delta)-\phi(x,t-\Delta)}{\Delta^2} \, ,
$$
i.e. it does not depend on the value at the specific point, but only on its neighbours. So, I created a 2D grid, assigned a random number to each point and then went as follows: For each point, I calculated $\square \phi$ and then set $\phi(x,t) = \left ( \frac{\square \phi(x,t)}{\lambda} \right )^{1/3}$. I then repeated the process several times. Total error, measured as sum of squares of differences between left and right hand sides of the equation, was indeed decreasing, but the results were completely unphysical (as in widely oscillating).

Could you please help me out with this?

SSF

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Normal you compute the source at the current time and spatial point. And you rearrange the scheme (at least in explicit) to have the latest time step being calculated from the the previous?

Comment: I want to do that so see how the equation behaves. I've done some approximate calculations and would like to see whether they match the actual behaviour. The source term depends on the field itself, wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: how do you mean the source term depends on the field itself? do you mean that it is a function of $\phi$? if so you tend to treat the source terms on the rhs (i am using an explicit scheme idea here) normally you want to have $\phi^{n+1}_k = \cdots$ where the rhs are all other terms. you usually get the lhs from the right limit (last time step) for which you want to predict.

Comment: what you are doing is something you would see in a root-finding method where you would solve $x_n = x_k^3\to x_k = (x_n)^{1/3}$ but you have mixture of "flow of time" on the right handside which you are updating a previous time step with a future time step. Doesn't make sense to me, especially since you initial boundary problem i.e. start at $t=0$.